# Tomcat not opening in browser

Tags: tomcat

im trying to run tomcat using startup.bat file in command prompt.The tomcat starts but when I try to open the tomcat localhost,it displays the following error on webpage.

> This page can’t be displayed
>
> Turn on TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, and TLS 1.2 in Advanced settings and try
>   connecting to https://localhost:9999  again. If this error persists,
>   contact your site administrator.

the tomcat server starts up properly but as soon as I open the localhost in browser it displays

> Error parsing http request header note:furthur occurrences of HTTP
>   header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level

The TLS1.0, TLS 1.1, TLS1.2 is turned on when I checked. I even tried changing the port numbers.

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was trying to use Internet explorer. It worked using chrome.